# Is it proper to ask geographically based questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it proper to ask geographically based career questions? For example, "What US city has the greatest opportunity for software engineers?"

Comment: In addition to what Jeff said, "What US city has the greatest opportunities" question is also too temporally localized: an area with great opportunities today may not have the same appeal in a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically no, as these would be too localized:

> **too localized**
>   This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

There can be exceptions, for example, on a poker site questions about Las Vegas would *certainly* be relevant, yes?

The rule of thumb is to generalize the question so it is relevant and helpful to as many people in *your* community as possible -- don't give someone a fish, teach them how to fish, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If it's likely to still be valuable in a year, eg. what user groups are there in the Houston area then yes.

If it's geographically and time limited, eg. is  Initrode in Houston hiring, then no